# Plotly Table not showing words with space

Tags: plotly

I'm using plotly to draw charts/table, and found issue when drawing a table.

At first when the page load the table looks fine, but after hiding it and redraw the table, values with spaces are not being displayed.

Any idea what is the cause?

hit 'hide' and then 'draw' and the example

```js
function hideTable(){
    $('#myDiv').hide();
}

function redrawTable(){
  
  var values = [
        ['Salaries val', 'Office', 'Merchandise val', 'Legal', '<b>TOTAL</b>'],
        [1200000, 20000, 80000, 2000, 12120000],
        [1300000, 20000, 70000, 2000, 130902000]]

  var data = [{
    type: 'table',
    header: {
      values: [["<b>EXPENSES</b>"], ["<b>Q1</b>"], ["<b>Q2</b>"]],
      align: "center",
      line: {width: 1, color: 'black'},
      fill: {color: "grey"},
      font: {family: "Arial", size: 12, color: "white"}
    },
    cells: {
      values: values,
      align: "center",
      line: {color: "black", width: 1},
      font: {family: "Arial", size: 11, color: ["black"]}
    }
  }]

  Plotly.plot('myDiv', data);
  $('#myDiv').show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    redrawTable();
});
```

```css
.btn {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
 <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <a class="btn" onclick="redrawTable();" >draw</a>
  <br/>
  <a class="btn" onclick="hideTable();"> hide</a>

  <div id="myDiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div></div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone face similar issue, I found how to fix it by replacing the lines.
Instead:

```
Plotly.plot('myDiv', data);
$('#myDiv').show();
```

I'm using:

```
$('#myDiv').show();
Plotly.plot('myDiv', data);
```